# Two data validation in the same cell

Tags: excel, database, validation, datatable, formula

I need to do a data validation for the user don't misstype the information that goes to the databank. The information in the cell must be filled with two criteria, the first part is the worker status, and the second information right after in the same cell is de contract code that he is working on. How can I do a data validation with this two information disposed in two diferent tables?
I tried something like =AND(LEFT(K3:Q999;4)=S3:S13;RIGHT(K3:Q999;2)=S15:S49)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw2x1.png)

Comment: So count the number of characters to be greater or equal to a minimum.

Answer (score -1):

It all depends on how you want to apply the validation.

If you want it to be in the cell in a drop down then standard validation will only work if you have every combination possible in it's own range, e.g. ...

```
19Exec
19Folg
19Disp
...
33Exec
33Folg
33Disp
... 
etc.
```

If you want, you can always do it using VBA.  A word of caution though, this will invalidate the undo stack and will likely need to be refined to ensure it caters for all scenarios.  It is very much an option though.

You need to change this code to suit you.  It's bare bones and works in a basic sense.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rngIntersect As Range, objCell As Range, strPrefix As String, strSuffix As String
    Dim lngIndexSuffix As Long, lngIndexPrefix As Long
    
    ' Safety net, remove if you think this won't be a problem.
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1000 Then Exit Sub
    
    For Each objCell In Target
        Set rngIntersect = Application.Intersect(objCell, Range("ValidationRange"))
        
        If Not rngIntersect Is Nothing Then
            If Len(objCell.Text) = 0 Then
                ' Only continue if the cell isn't empty.
                Target.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
            Else
                strSuffix = Right(objCell.Text, 4)
                strPrefix = Mid(objCell.Text, 1, Len(objCell.Text) - Len(strSuffix))

                Err.Clear
                
                On Error Resume Next
                
                lngIndexPrefix = WorksheetFunction.Match(CInt(strPrefix), Range("Range1"), 0)
                lngIndexSuffix = WorksheetFunction.Match(strSuffix, Range("Range2"), 0)
                
                If Err.Description <> "" Then
                    Target.Interior.Color = 255
                Else
                    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142
                End If
                
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

To make this work, create a named range over both key columns in your lookup tables.  The numbers (i.e. 19, 33, 43, etc.) I have named "**Range1**" and the 4 character words (e.g. Exec, Folg, Disp, etc.) I have named "**Range2**".

For the range of cells you want to run the validation check for, I called that "**ValidationRange**".

Throw that macro into the worksheet that has the range you want to validate and see how it goes.

Comment: Thank you!! I was thinking in something like that. I will try. Thank you again!

Comment: @HenriqueMonteiro, did it work for you?